# R reading pdf remove special char

Tags: r, pdf

i'm trying to import raw text data from pdf and i have text like `250 μm` with `pdf_text`from `pdftools` and it remove the special character and give me `250 m`, i tried `read_pdf` from `textreadr` it give me `<U+0095>m` any tips to get the raw data without messing unity.

i can't share the source (pdf)
my script:

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(textreadr)

all_pdfs <- list.files(pattern = ".pdf$")
dat_txt <- map_df(all_pdfs, ~ data_frame(text = pdf_text(.x),
                                         titre =  pdf_info(.x)$keys$Title ,
                                         auteur =  pdf_info(.x)$keys$Author 
)) %>% mutate( 
  text = str_replace_all(text,"dr\\.|DR\\.|Dr\\.", "dr" ) , # suppression . après dr
  text = str_replace_all(text,"e\\.g\\.", "eg" ), # idem pour e.g.
  text = str_replace_all(text,"Page\\s[[:digit:]]\\sof\\s[[:digit:]]", "" ) # supression N° page of
) %>%
  unnest_tokens(text, text , token ="sentences")
```

edit the metadata

```
[1] "<?xpacket begin='ï»¿' 
id='W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d'?>
<?adobe-xap-filters esc=\"CRLF\"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x='adobe:ns:meta/' x:xmptk='XMP toolkit 2.9.1-13, framework 1.6'>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#' xmlns:iX='http://ns.adobe.com/iX/1.0/'>\
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:110d9367-d653-11e5-0000-9c55a6090709' xmlns:pdf='http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/' pdf:Producer='GPL Ghostscript 9.10'/>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:110d9367-d653-11e5-0000-9c55a6090709' xmlns:xmp='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/'><xmp:ModifyDate>2016-02-15T16:19:55+01:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
<xmp:CreateDate>2016-02-15T16:19:55+01:00</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:CreatorTool>FreePDF 4.09f - http://shbox.de</xmp:CreatorTool></rdf:Description><rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:110d9367-d653-11e5-0000-9c55a6090709' xmlns:xapMM='http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/' xapMM:DocumentID='uuid:110d9367-d653-11e5-0000-9c55a6090709'/>
<rdf:Description rdf:about='uuid:110d9367-d653-11e5-0000-9c55a6090709' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/' dc:format='application/pdf'><dc:title><rdf:Alt><rdf:li xml:lang='x-default'>confidentiel</rdf:li></rdf:Alt></dc:title><dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>createur</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator></rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end='w'?>"
```

Comment: well i checked again it's 250 <U+0095>m in my data.frame and 250 μm in the pdf. i can replace the char manually but it's not a clean import

Comment: Actually `textreadr` uses `read_pdf` from `pdftool` to read in the data and then change the encoding to "UTF-8" so the harm is already done for μ, it as already be converted to a "message waiting" sign...

Comment: You can try `extract_text() `from https://github.com/hrbrmstr/pdfbox but I don't have your document so I don't know what it's going to do w/o an external test.

Comment: Have you checked the information on the pdf (meta information) manually with respect to encoding? Maybe you will find a clue there. Another issue could be that the creator of the pdf copied the symbol from a source with an encoding different as set for the pdf. Hence, when reading the pdf with one fixed encoding the second encoding is recognized incorrectly. At least, I have encountered this problem once.

Comment: I tried to copy/paste the line in a pdf and read it with pdf_text and the μ sugn was read without any problem so definitely we'll need to know more about the source to help you

Comment: I put the metadata in the main post, when icopy paste the `` it's not appearing there's a weird box instead working maybe they pasted a weird μ sign

Comment: very likely, like an image maybe inside text ?

Comment: my only choice it to replace manually thx

Comment: Can you give a link to a PDF file? It would be useful to provide a solution.